# What is the intention of putting return values in parentheses in C/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, return-value, parentheses

I've come across some code that surrounds the return value from a method/function in parentheses.

What does that do?

The code I saw took an image, resized it and then returned it.

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    //
    // some fascinating, but irrelevant, resizing code here
    //

    return (image);
}
```

Comment: People like making `return` look like a function call?  Google style guide says shame on them: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Return_Values

Comment: @Nick T: I once met a guy that thought return _was_ a function…

Comment: @Nick T: Couple of problems with that advice. 1) It is a C++ style guide. @) Unless you are working at google its probably got some bad general advice (good for google code bad for general C++).

Comment: @Martin York: I use it for C.  Yes, I understand it's for C++, but there is some overlap between the two languages (and presumably Obj-C), and having some sort of style guide is nice.  I do have a brain, and I deviate when I have a reason to, but I fail to see how you could have one for this case (parenthesizing return expressions).

Comment: @Nick T: I fail to see why this needs to be in a style guide. It does no harm it does not make it hard to read (If used judiciously it could even make it easier to read). But the Google style guide is well known to be designed for Google internally where they have specific requirements because of an aged code base. Applying this to modern C++ is not seen as a good idea (at least in my opinion) and using it as a reference for giving advice without context is just bad advice.

Comment: @Martin York: 1) I wasn't even giving any advice, I was just giving a reason for *why* people might do that.  2) Context (as per question): Putting return values in parentheses.  3) If the new standard in the C++ world is to senselessly parenthesize everything, then I guess that's great.  Probably why I hate C++ so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least as far as C is concerned, it makes no difference.  The parens aren't necessary, but they don't change the meaning of the return statement.  The grammar of the return statement is

```
return-statement:
    return expressionopt ;
```

and one of the productions of the *expression* non-terminal is a *parenthesized-expression*, or **(** *expression* **)**.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. It is completely useless.

It overrides operator precedence, yet no operator will have a lower precedence than "return".

Comment: You mean, no operator will have *lower* "precedence" than `return`. Which isn't an operator...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is simply that it's a style choice, like using "/* comments */" instead of "//comments"

Comment: `//` comments are not really a style choice, because they are allowed since C99. If you program against the old standard, you better don't use them if you want to write conforming code.

Comment: I think the compiler I use doesn't even complain when you compile `//` comments with the strict ANSI flag set (C89 is the default, C99 isn't really supported)

Comment: @Nick: Often the ANSI semantics flag is separate from the all-warnings flag.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is equivalent of typing the return without the parentheses. Typically, you would use parentheses for type casting, or if you want to treat an expression as an independent block.

For example:

```
// This is an untyped pointer to an instance of SomeClass
void* ptr = instance;

// In order to let the compiler know that ptr is an instance of SomeClass
// we cast it, and then we put the cast in parentheses to be able to access
// a property on the result of the cast.
return ((SomeClass *)ptr).someproperty;
```

Comment: Don't you need `->` in place of `.`? And a `;` at the end?

Comment: `x->y` is synonymous with `(*x).y`, so you would be double dereferencing.  I'm not sure how casting would work with member access, but `((SomeClass)ptr)->someproperty` might work

Comment: In Obj-C, you can use the dot syntax when accessing properties. So [code]((SomeClass *)ptr).someproperty;[/code] is equivalent to [code][(SomeClass *)ptr someproperty];[/code]
And yep, I forgot the semi-colon :)